# analytic subvariety being union of locally finite irreducible components

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

There is a statement in Huybrechts complex geometry that says that

> analytic hypersurface(analytic subvariety of codimension 1) is the
> union of locally finite irreducible components.

I was trying to prove this claim, and I found it quite likely to use the fact that: an analytic germ is a finite union of irreducible components, and the decomposition is unique.

---

My attempt:
First pick any point $x\in A \subset X$ where $A$ is analytic subvariety, then $(A,x)$ is an analytic germ by the definition. Assume $A = \cup A_i$ with $A_i$ are irreducible analytic subvariety.

if it's not locally finite at some point $y\in A$, then my idea is $(A,y)$ will have infinite many component, however I don't know how to compute the germ of the union $(\cup A_i,y) = \cup_{j\in J} (A_j,y)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, each component of the germ $(A,x)$ is contained in a unique irreducible component of the hypersurface $A$: Let $Z$ be an irreducible component of the germ $(A,x)$. Then $Z$ is an irreducible subset of $A$, and since the irreducible components $A_1, A_2, \dotsc$ of $A$ are maximal irreducible subsets, $Z$ is contained in one component, say $Z \subset A_1$. If $Z$ is contained in another component, say $Z \subset A_2$, then $Z \subset A_1 \cap A_2$. But both germs $(A_1,x)$ and $(A_2,x)$ have distinct irreducible components, which are irreducible components of $(A,x)$. So $Z$ is contained in two different irreducible components of $(A,x)$, which contradicts the maximality of $Z$ with respect to irreducible germs.

This means you get a map
$$\{\, \text{components of } (A,x) \} \to \{\, \text{components of } A\,\}.$$
Clearly, every component of $A$ that contains $x$ is in the image of that map. Since the domain is a finite set, there are only finitely many components of $A$ which contain $x$.

Comment: @yili I added an explanation. Hope that helps.

Comment: I have two question left : (1) why if $Z$ is irreducible component of germ then $Z$ is irreducible subset of $A$ (2) why the germ $(A_1,x)$ and $(A_2,x)$ has distinct irreducible componenet? @red_trumpet

Comment: Hello @red_trumpet , can you say more about the question in the comment?

Comment: @yili I think (1) should follow from the definition of irreducible germ, if you make $Z$ small enough. Take a look at chapter 1 of Huybrechts' book. For (2) I don't have a good argument right now. My intuition is that a Zariski closed, irreducible subset should be determined by an irreducible germ at a point, the rest being obtained by analytic continuation. But that's still pretty handwavy...

Comment: A more precise formulation for (1) is probably "An irreducible germ at $x$ can be represented by an irreducible closed subset of an open neighbourhood $U$ of $x$".

Comment: To check my understanding the irreducible germ has irreducible set as representive. However the irreducible analytic set needs not to have irreducible germ at some point correct? Huybrechts defines the irreducible germ using that if $(A,x) = (A_1,x) \cup (A_2,x)$ then $(A,x) = (A_i,x)$ for one of $(A_i,x)$ but the definition didn't say that $A_i$ is irreducible set